# How to ensure brackets are always the same size in an equation?

Tags: equations

I am writing an equation, but the size of the brackets changes throughout.

I am using the code

```
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:G_K}
G_{ij}^{l} = \left \langle \psi_l | V_i V_j|\psi_l \right \rangle 
           - \left \langle \psi_l | V_i|\psi_l \right \rangle
             \left \langle \psi_l | V_j|\psi_l \right \rangle \; .
\end{equation}
```

and I get the output:

[image]

Note, the size of the square brackets in the second term.

How can I re-write my equation, to make the size of the brackets uniform?

Comment: don't use left and right, use `\bigl`... `\bigr`  (or a different size such as `\Bigl` or `\biggl`. But in this case you don't need big at all so just use `\langle` and `\rangle` wth no prefix

Comment: The `braket` package might also be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can notice that the different sizes appear for items containing a subscript j, which has larger depth (that is, it extended more below the baseline) than the other subscripts and the bar.

Some guides and practices suggest always using `\left` and `\right`. Actually, experienced users and good guides will tell you that you *shouldn't* use `\left` and `\right` unless there are reasons to, which is not really frequent.

There is no reason for the delimiters to vertically extend to cover every symbol between them.

[image]

The former is `$(a+b^2)^2$` and the latter is `$\left(a+b^2\right)^2$`. Here opinions may vary, but the aim is to obtain an inline formula that is as inobtrusive as possible, while keeping readability.

Here's the output if you remove `\left` and `\right`, but also use `\,|\,` instead of the simple bar

[image]

Without the thin spaces it's too crowded:

[image]